# SQL Table Design: Data in rows vs data in columns

Tags: database-design

While developing a college application, I have to choose either of the following approaches for storing marks of students,

First Approach:

[Student_ID, Subject1_Marks, Subject2_Marks, Subject3_Marks, Subject4_Marks, Subject5_Marks]

1, 67, 78, 65, 89, 77

2, 62, 61, 81, 66, 73

Second Approach:

[StudentID, SubjectID, Marks]

1, 1, 67

1, 2, 78

1, 3, 65

1, 4, 89

1, 5, 77

2, 1, 62

2, 2, 61

2, 3, 81

2, 4, 66

2, 5, 73

I have eliminated other columns for simplification purposes. Every year 500-600 students get enrolled. Needless to say, there will be a "sum" operation on the marks.  I was wondering what approach would take lesser read/write time and lesser database size. I am using SQL Server 2019 with C# (Visual Studio 2019).

Comment: My suggestion is to use first approach. The reason is you can easily retrieve the data from a single row, and the number of rows will be reduce and mainly if you need to add extra subject you can add it at end easily.

Answer (score 0):

The second is better, one student, one subject, one mark
fits the table design normal form